# Autoload Class not found

Tags: php, class, composer-php, autoload

I can't seem to figure out why i keep getting this error even though everything seems correct.

My Composer.json looks like this:

```
{
      "autoload": {
            "psr-4": {
           "Datechecker\\": "lib/",
               "App\\": "app/"
        }
      }
    }
```

And my class looks like this:

```
<?

namespace Datechecker;

class App
{
    public function runCommand(array $argv){
    $name = "World";
    if(isset($argv[1])){
        $name = $argv[1];
        }

    echo "Hello $name!!!\n";
    }

}
```

Then my executable file looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?

require_DIR_.'/vendor/autoload.php';

if (php_sapi_name() !== 'cli') {
    exit;
}


use Datechecker\App;

$app = new App();
$app->runCommand($argv);
?>
```

I have tried to follow similar questions which i came across on here but none of the solutions seem to be working for me. Please help.

**Update**

Classes structure looks like this:

```
lib/
  App.php
app/
vendor/
  composer/
     ...
  autoload.php
datechecker
composer.json
```

Comment: Have you run composer dump-autoload after change?

Comment: What is "this error"? Can you share the exact error message, and your attempts to resolve the error?

Comment: Also, please share the file structure of your classes

Comment: @Beniamin Yes i have tried composer dump-autoload after change

Comment: @NicoHaase the error is "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Datechecker\App' not found"

Comment: @NicoHaase I have updated the question and added the file structure

Comment: Does your `datechecker`  file really contain `require_DIR_` **without** a space between `require`  and `__DIR__` ? Also, does it contain **two** lower dashes before and after ` DIR`?